# How to treat $ in XML?

Tags: python, xml

ElementTree throws an exception for `<PRP$>`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in xml
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1301, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1643, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1507, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 28, column 14
```

I got this output from Stanford NLP package. Is it truly malformed? Wikipedia and other sources dont mention it.

How to solve this? I would want to replace `$` by its corresponding entity if I knew what it was.

Comment: The [list of valid characters in a tag name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameChar) is too much effort for me to parse right now. You can't use character references in tag names though, so that won't be the solution.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#d0e804 says no.

Comment: Looking at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Name shows that `$` is *not* a valid XML name character.

Comment: Can I replace it with something else?

Comment: don't agree... unicode wide dollar sign (0xff04) is a valid XML name character. Ascii dollar sign (0x0024) is not though.

Comment: @aitchnyu You could use `&#36;` probably. See [dollar](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/24/index.htm)

Comment: @DarkCthulhu: This is a *element name*, not XML text data.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Then it just isn't valid.

Comment: I do not see any way for the [Stanford NLP output](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp_output.html) to use *elements* for the classification tags, btw.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I used http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html#indentedXMLPrint(java.io.PrintWriter,%20boolean)

Comment: @aitchnyu: Right, and for any classification tag with a `$` that does output malformed XML then.

Comment: BTW, any reason you are not using the Python [`nltk` toolkit](http://nltk.org/)? It supports the Stanford tagger, among others, and you won't have to parse any XML yourself.